# Dreamweaver 8 is not working on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, dreamweaver

I'm using Dreamweaver as the editor for my projects.

Recently I moved to Windows 7, the Dreamweaver software is installed without any error.

When I tried to open the files from Dreamweaver file->open menu it stops working and closes by itself.

This is really annoying. Sometimes I'm losing data also.

The same setup file is working fine in Windows XP.

Is there any chance to fix this problem? (except upgrading the Dreamweaver software to newer version)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before installing or upgrading anything, try this:
Locate DreamWeaver's executable, right-click it and select the "Compatibility" tab. There, select XP version (try various service packs):

[image]

Click OK to save, and then run the application.

Answer (score 1):

1. Locate `dreamweaver.exe` in Dreamweaver's folder inside Program Files.
2. Right click the file and choose *Troubleshoot compatbility*.
3. Follow the steps - it will look something like this:

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. We simply moved it into an XP vmware. If you do not have Vmware, simply use the Win 7 "XP mode":
http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-PC/download.aspx

Comment: XP Mode is only available for Windows 7 Professional, Enterprise, and Ultimate.  If you have Home Premium/Basic, you'll have to download and set it up yourself, and supply an XP CD and License Key.

Answer (score 0):

From what others folks in saying on various forums, it looks like you'll need the [8.0.2 update for dreamweaver](https://www.adobe.com/support/dreamweaver/downloads_updaters.html#dw8) and compatibility mode set to XP SP2 (see Traveling Tech Guy's post)

If that doesn't work, or try here: http://www.nickbartlett.com/wordpress/dreamweaver-8-crashes-or-shuts-down-on-windows-7/

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of angst and messing about, removing, reinstalling, changing the compatibility mode, deleting registry keys, you name it I had a hunch the issue was something to do with the site(s) cache.

I save my websites in a folder on the C: drive named 'Sites' I renamed this 'SitesSAFE' and then opened Dreamweaver. Problem solved!

I then deleted all the sites in the Site Manager in Dreamweaver. Closed the program and re-opened it. Closed the program and renamed the 'SitesSAFE' folder back to 'Sites'. I still have the annoying issue where I have to remove and import the site every time, as DW8 is not remembering the FTP passwords, but I don't care. I can live with that.

Dreamweaver 8 is running in compatibility mode for Windows 7. Nothing else is checked. I have uploaded an image if you can go to the link below.

[image: Compatibility Settings]

I have used DW in it's various guises since the year dot. Bring back Macromedia... I begrudge companies forcing me to pay a subscription for software. It's a cash cow for them and a drain for the users. I also prefer to program mainly in ColdFusion and Adobe have dropped support for ColdFusion in the latest version of Dreamweaver. I also code in .NET and trust me, ColdFusion is by far the better language, but hey the Microsoft bullies appear to be winning the day, once again!  Good Luck...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, what I did was rename the sitecashe, which was in user/appdata/Roaming, but when DW8 started (it was crashing on startup) it tried to check or recreate the cashe and it again crashed.  I restarted and stopped it from creating cashe, that appears to work.  I had uninstalled DW8 a number of times and tried to remove all files, but when it came up, it had all of my sites, so that stuff doesn't get removed when you try to uninstall.  It runs just fine on Win7 Pro and has on this computer for years, before it started the crashing.  I also have it on a Win10 computer with no issues.

Comment: Welcome to Super User William! I have edited your answer to make it read more like a set of instructions than "I had this problem and here's what I tried". If you disagree with the edit, you can [edit it yourself](https://superuser.com/posts/1297440/edit) or revert the changes :)